# Handling 'If' statements in .aspx files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

One of my code behind file is sending some boolean value (read from the data base) to the corresponding.aspx file. I want to change the css style class of the container division based on this boolean value. I tried to do it the following way,

code behind file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Result.InnerText = "false";  //In real scenario, this is retrieved from a db
}
```

aspx file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<% if (Result.InnerText == "true") { Result.Style["Color"] = "#000000"; } else { Result.Style["Color"] = "#ff0000"; } %>
<div id="Result" runat="server">
</div>
</form>
```

Its seems to be working properly, but I am not satisfied with this snippet. Is this the way to do it?? I am doing it properly ???

**UPDATE:**

Are there any other way to do this ? If so which is the better one ? Note: I must be able to change the css class name (applied to the division) whenever required

Answer (score 3):

Your Result Div is wired up in the codebehind so you don't need to put the if statement in the ASPX at all.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Result.InnerText = "false";  //In real scenario, this is retrieved from a db

    if (Result.InnerText == "true") {
        Result.Style["Color"] = "#000000";
    } else {
        Result.Style["Color"] = "#ff0000";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First I would create a public variable, say `result`. Then in your .aspx do this:

```
<div id="result" class='<%=(result?"someClass":"someOtherClass") %>'>
    Your text
</div>
```

Or if you want to do it all on the backend (.aspx):

```
<div id="result" runat="server">
    Your text
</div>
```

.cs

```
if (result) {
    result.CssClass = "yourClass";
} else {
    result.CssClass = "anotherClass";
}
```

Comment: can you explain on this a bit more ?

Comment: c# doesn't have an "iif". I think it should be this...
result ?"someClass":"someOtherClass"

Answer (score 2):

You could set the color in c# (code behind) after the line, where you get the variable value from the DB.

```
Result.Style["Color"] = (myDBVariable == "false") ? "#000000" : "#ff0000";
```

Comment: why? any particular reason? If you write c# code (either in code-behind or inline with aspx page), it will become 1 class file.

Comment: Its a presentation logic, isn't it ? so i want to have it separated out from the business logic file

Comment: It is a presentation thing. But, you are writing code inside an asp.net page (which has page load, init event). Isn't that part of presentation already?

Comment: Yep. So can you give me a neat solution for this problem ? My objective is simple, if the value is true, i want some css class to be added to that tag, else some other css class. It needn't be like the snippet I had mentioned above.

Comment: Well, you could construct javascript using the c# code & push it as RegisterStartupScript? I am just throwing in options that I can think of. Not sure, what you mean by better way?